# filter Object by two arguments java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of User object which have Date string,id and value. How do I filter the ArrayList of User's , which matches date value.

User Object is like this

```
  String accountId;
  String date;
  String value;

  User user = new User();
  user.setAccountId("101");
  user.setDate("20180506");
  user.setValue("David");

  ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
  userList.add(user)
```

Filter

I tried something like this which is not working

```
userList.stream()
        .filter(c -> userList.contains(date))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You should actually interact with `c` somehow in your filter lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current approach is incorrect as you're not using the identifier `c` which represents a `User` object and you're checking if the `userList` contains a string which is again incorrect.

instead the `filter` should be:

```
userList.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getDate().equals(date))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```